# Spring MVC - Response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I access the response object from a bean? To get the request object I use the following.

```
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) 
        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
```

Is there something similar to the above for response object?

Comment: Check Bozho's answer here: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6984252/433789 "@Autowired HttpServletResponse")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in a web application context (which it looks like you are) you can auto wire in the HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse.

The request/response from the current request scope will be injected.

```
@Component
public class SomeComponentInAWebApplicationContext {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I see that the answer has been accepted, but I'm unclear on this could work - where in Spring are these dependencies injected from? Trying it out, it fails as expected: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse] found for dependency. Am I missing something?

Comment: The component must be part of a WebApplicationContext i.e. one started from a -servlet.xml context.

Comment: Request and response will be wired only once.